# How to keep text formatting when updating 'Linked' txt files in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

With the option of 'Create Links When Placing Text and Spreadsheet Files' enabled in InDesign, is it possible having a `txt` file (plain text) that is continuously updated outside InDesign to keep the formatting inside InDesign?

In InDesign, whenever I update the Link of the text box all formatting is lost.

Answer (score 1):

For a table: Make a table style you point out during importing excel ("show import options" when placing and then choose the desired style).

For text look at this tutorial from Lynda.com http://www.lynda.com/articles/indesign-secrets-how-to-place-and-link-text-without-its-formatting

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out to maintain formatting to all text boxes, however it took me a while since you only gave me a link and it wasn't straightaway visible. This solution applies the same formatting style to all boxes, so it doesn't really help to maintain individual formatting styles

Comment: Im searching for this method as well, dont understand why they dont have this in Indesign? This is very useful and a HUGE time saver if its possible